# How to conditionally slice a dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Consider a pandas DataFrame constructed like:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({'a':['one','two','three']})
```

then I can locate the specific row of the dataframe containing `two` like:

```
df[df.a == 'two']
```

but so far the only way I have found to subset the `DataFrame` up to this row is like:

```
df[:df[df.a == 'two'].index[0]]
```

but that is quite ugly, so:

Is there a more appropriate way to accomplish this subsetting?

Specifically, I am interested in how to slice the DataFrame between row indices where a given column matches some arbitrary text string (in this case 'two'). For this particular case it would be equivalent to `df[:2]`. In general however, the ability to locate an index for the start and/or end of a slice based on column values seems like a reasonable thing?

one last example, maybe will help; I would expect to be able to do something like this:

`df[df.a == 'one' : df.a == 'three']`

to get a slice containing rows 1 & 2 of the DataFrame, equivalent to df[0:3]

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Does `df[df.a == 'two']` give you what you want? Where does the slice come in here? Or maybe you are looking for `df[df.a == 'two'].reset_index(drop=True)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to identify the indices for a particular start and stop values and get the matching rows plus all the rows in between. One way is to find the indexes and build a range, but you already said that you don't like that approach. Here is a general solution using boolean logic that should work for you.

First, let's make a more interesting example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['one','two','three', 'four', 'five']})
```

Suppose `start = "two"` and `stop = "four"`. That is, you want to get the following output DataFrame:

```
       a
1    two
2  three
3   four
```

We can find the index of the bounding rows via:

```
df["a"].isin({start, stop})
#0    False
#1     True
#2    False
#3     True
#4    False
#Name: a, dtype: bool
```

If the value for index 2 were `True`, we would be done as we could just use this output as a mask. So let's find a way to create the mask we need.

First we can use `cummax()` and the boolean XOR operator (`^`) to achieve:

```
(df["a"]==start).cummax() ^ (df["a"]==stop).cummax()
#0    False
#1     True
#2     True
#3    False
#4    False
#Name: a, dtype: bool
```

This is almost what we want, except we are missing the stop value index. So let's just bitwise OR (`|`) the stop condition:

```
#0    False
#1     True
#2     True
#3     True
#4    False
#Name: a, dtype: bool
```

This gets the result we are looking for. So create a mask, and index the dataframe:

```
mask = (df["a"]==start).cummax() ^ (df["a"]==stop).cummax() | (df["a"]==stop)
print(df[mask])
#       a
#1    two
#2  three
#3   four
```

We can extend these findings into a function that also supports indexing up to a row or indexing from a row to the end:

```
def get_rows(df, col, start, stop):
    if start is None:
        mask = ~((df[col] == stop).cummax() ^ (df[col] == stop))
    else:
        mask = (df[col]==start).cummax() ^ (df[col]==stop).cummax() | (df[col]==stop)
    return df[mask]

# get rows between "two" and "four" inclusive
print(get_rows(df=df, col="a", start="two", stop="four"))
#       a
#1    two
#2  three
#3   four

# get rows from "two" until the end
print(get_rows(df=df, col="a", start="two", stop=None))
#       a
#1    two
#2  three
#3   four
#4   five

# get rows up to "two"
print(get_rows(df=df, col="a", start=None, stop="two"))
#     a
#0  one
#1  two
```

---

**Update**:

For completeness, here is the indexing based solution.

```
def get_rows_indexing(df, col, start, stop):
    min_ind = min(df.index[df[col]==start].tolist() or [0])
    max_ind = max(df.index[df[col]==stop].tolist() or [len(df)])
    return df[min_ind:max_ind+1]
```

This function does essentially the same thing as the other version, but it may be easier to understand. Also this is more robust, as the other version relies on `None` not being a value in the desired column.

Comment: Thank you for that indepth treatment of pandas indexing. I am new to pandas in general and still processing some of what you have said but it really is quite helpful. 

I can't help but wonder why this 'get_rows' feature you have implemented isn't built into the DataFrame API for slicing... I mean given that the index into a DataFrame can be a condition or a slice it would seem an obvious extension to add support for defining a slice in terms of two conditions.

At any rate, thank you for your insightful answer.

Comment: @Travis there may well be an easier way/built-in to do that, but I have not seen it before. (pandas is a large library and I am not an expert). In any case, I added an update with the index-based approach. You may find that simpler.

Answer (score 1):

If you temorarily use column 'a' as an index, then the locate method (loc) does exactly what you are asking.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['one','two','three', 'four', 'five']})
start = 'two'
stop = 'four'
df = df.set_index('a').loc[start:stop].reset_index()
```

Comment: "loc", short for locate I think, does exactly what the original question was about. So df.loc["two", "four"] gives all records from label "two" to label "four" (inclusive)

The complication is that loc only works on the index, not other columns. Hence the set_index to column a then set it back again afterwards.